# How can i write to the CMD from the Arduino?

Tags: cmd, arduino

I need to send some syntax to be printed on the cmd from the Arduino.

the Symtax shuld be the below line:

```
"bartend.exe /F=C:\Users\feniger\Desktop\BarTenderFiles\PSLableV03.btw /P"
```

thanks, Yaron

Comment: Emulate a keyboard.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here. Are you trying to take remote control of a Windows PC from an Arduino? How are they connected? Are you trying to launch a command line shell or is it already running?

Comment: Hi. The Arduino is conected by Serial conection to the PC. I would like to launch a command line. I need to write the below syntax to the CMD - once some triger in the Arduino is activated: "bartend.exe /F=C:\Users\feniger\Desktop\BarTenderFiles\PSLableV03.btw /P"

Answer (score 0):

This requires you to emulate keyboard via Arduino. For that the simplest approach would be to use **Arduino Leonardo** or **Arduino Leonardo Pro Micro**. With this just you can input any string to anywhere e.g. terminal, text editor etc.

If you cant find these boards, search for Arduino with Atmega32u4 controller. The Atmega32u4 controlled has USB capabilities which can solve your problem.

For windows cmd you can use following code to open command prompt and auto type desired command.

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

void setup() {
    // initialize control over the keyboard:
    Keyboard.begin();

    // first open run by windows + r
    Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
    Keyboard.press('r');
    Keyboard.releaseAll();

    // adjust delay according to your requierment
    delay(4000);

    // press enter to open cmd
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();

    // adjust delay according to your requierment
    delay(4000);

    // commond to be entered
    char* cmd = "bartend.exe /F=C:\Users\feniger\Desktop\BarTenderFiles\PSLableV03.btw /P";
    // print command to cmd
    Keyboard.print(cmd);
    delay(50);

    // press enter to run cmd
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: hi thanks! I am working with a Arduino Leonardo. well - what shuld i do in order to write to the CMD?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check it. i hope everything is clear now.